# Flex menu not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

You can check my main menu flex here:
http://funnyfrontend.com/

This menu works fine in Chrome and IE11.

Thaks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put display:flex for firefox.

```
.secondary-navigation ul.creative-menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```